# Shadows are choppy on Android, but look fine in Unity Editor on my PC

Tags: unity, android, lighting, shadows, settings

Here is a gif of what I'm seeing with my shadows on my Android device:

https://gfycat.com/VapidTestyFrigatebird

That shadow looks perfectly fine from any angle / distance in my Unity editor, however.  I don't know much about shadows in Unity yet, but here's a bit more info about my settings:

**Directional Light Settings**

[image]

**Shadow Quality Settings**

[image]

Has anyone experienced an issue similar to this before?  How do I fix this shadow choppiness?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly shadow cascades aren't supported (yet) on Android / Mobile.

Try disabling the shadow cascades.